# Select all columns then sample, or select IDs only then join and sample?

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**Problem:** Assuming we're looking at 10 billion rows of numerical data, where the FROM clause excludes 99% of entries, which method would you expect to perform better and why?

I could argue either way, but then again, I have maybe 6 months SQL experience and no formal compsci education. Problem is formatted in ANSI Snowflake SQL.

**Method 1:** Sample all columns (with conditions).

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3.... coln
FROM table1
WHERE cond1 and cond2 and cond3... condn
SAMPLE (1000000 rows)
```

**Method 2:** Sample IDs only (with conditions) then join.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT IDcol
    FROM table1
    WHERE cond1 and cond2 and cond3... condn
    SAMPLE (1000000 rows)
    ) as t1sampled
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT col1, col2, col3.... coln
    FROM table1
    ) as t1
ON t1sampled.IDcol = t1.IDcol
```

Comment: Try them and report back.

Comment: It's actually possible that Snowflake would create the exact same profile for each of these, so it really depends on the data and how the profiler creates an execution plan.  BTW - Method 3 could leverage a CTE, which could also create a different execution plan and perform differently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff reporting in. 

Mike, I included the query profiles to demystify what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Similar run times!**

I modified the above methods to sample 10,000 rows (not 1,000,000), because this new warehouse had less migrated data than I first thought.

I used our extra small/light (XS) Snowflake warehouse.

**Method 1:** 6 minutes; 75 GB read

[image: Method 1: 6 minutes; 75 GB read]

**Method 2:** 6 minutes 2 seconds; 90 GB read

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first approach is better I think. There is no need to join the table back onto itself, it's added complexity that isn't required and ultimately it produces the same result either way. Mike already mentioned that the query compiler may even create the same plan for both queries anyway...

Also FYI. [Block sampling](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/sample.html#fraction-based-block-sampling-with-seeds) is significantly faster than row sampling but it may bias your results if you have small tables or if your micro partitions contain similar data (biased towards ingestion pattern if the table isn't clustered?).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
I don't understand block clustering though. The link doesn't explain it, and [others have been confused](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009a8c5vSAA/about-the-the-tablesamplesample-clause-the-system-block-option-are-the-blocks-based-on-the-tables-micropartition). Block size would determine whether I'd use it or not, because if I was looking at device usage, block size could bias towards different time zones. I'd stick with random sampling by default unless I could confidently argue block sampling doesn't bias the extraction.

Comment: Good point, I just assumed that a block was a micro-partition but that might not be true!